# Database design for a list of task with subtask

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I want to create a database that keeps track of a list of tasks that the users need to do and in the list of tasks there will be subtasks and sub-subtasks and so on. So my question is how to design this kind of database?

**Example: A picture of the tasks and subtasks**

[image: a picture of the tasks and subtasks]

For this kind of database, should I create only 4 tables for the main task, sub task, sub-subtask and sub-sub-sub task or is there a better way of doing it? What if the users want more subtasks? Should I create a fifth table or should I just restrict the number of subtasks available. I feel like having this many tables in a database just for the subtasks is a bad database design

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have basically a tree of tasks. It should be possible to add a foreign key column to the task entity that references it's parent task. The nesting can be as deep as you desire and there is no need for subtask tables.

Comment: Oh never thought of that...so basically just create a table called Task that has a recursive relationship with itself. Thanks for answering the question~